# How to merge two NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, algorithm, ipad

I would know how to merge two array which contain some duplicate :
Here is an exemple to illustrate what I want to do :

```
// Here is some dictionary which contain an unique "id" key.
NSDictionary *dico1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"11111111", @"id", nil];
NSDictionary *dico2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"22222222", @"id", nil];
NSDictionary *dico3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"33333333", @"id", nil];
NSDictionary *dico4 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"44444444", @"id", nil];
NSDictionary *dico5 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"55555555", @"id", nil];

// And here is duplicates of the 2nd and 3td dictionary.
NSDictionary *dico2_bis = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"22222222", @"id", nil];
NSDictionary *dico3_bis = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"33333333", @"id", nil];
```

And now I have an array which contain some of those dictionaries :

```
NSArray *currentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         dico1, dico2, dico3, nil];
```

And here is the new array to be merged with the first one which contain some duplicate and new "data" :

```
NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      dico2_bis, dico3_bis, dico4, dico5, nil];
```

My goal, at the final stage, is to have an array which contains all dictionaries with all duplicate deleted

```
NSArray *finalArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       dico1, dico2, dico3, dico4, dico5, nil];
```

I don't know how what is the most efficient solution, the merge do have to be fast. Do I have to implement a fast enumeration or a block based enumeration algorithm, or maybe a NSPredicate implementation ?.
I've already search about NSPredicate but I've not found a way to filter an array with an other array =/ 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry about this word (google translate, i hate you! :D) I would mean, as Thorsten S. said, a duplicate. Sorry about the confusion. My question was edited.

Comment: @kl94: Can the dictionaries have other keys besides the "id"? What should happen if you have 2 dictionaries with the same id but different other keys/values?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, the dictionaries should have more than one key, I removed them in order to be easy to illustrate my problems. By the way, if we have 2 dictionaries with the same id but different other keys/values. We should keep the new one but this scenario should never happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use NSArrays, what you need is a set which automatically eliminates "duplicates" (a "doubloon" is a Spanish gold coin). So you are using simply an NSMutableSet and add your NSDictionaries to it.

```
NSMutableSet aSet = [NSMutableSet new];
[aSet addObject:dico1];
....
```

Comment: I didn't know NSSet delete automatically duplicates. It works really well but it doesn't work with custom Objects. I was looking more for a solution which allow to filter with a given "key". Have you a suggestion ?

Comment: If you have custom objects, you need to overwrite hash: and isEqual:. hash: return an NSUInteger which should be equal for two objects (but may be equal for two different objects, it should be simply fast) and isEqual: to test for exact equality.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
NSArray *hasDuplicates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first", @"second", @"first", nil];
NSArray *noDuplicates = [[NSSet setWithArray: hasDuplicates] allObjects];

NSLog(@"%@ %@",hasDuplicates,noDuplicates);
```

Comment: It works but it assumes I'd already added the tempArray to the currentArray (with all duplicates it can contains). I don't think it's the most efficient way to merge two array. But thanks anyway for learning me NSSet treats duplicates automatically.

Comment: Form Thorsten S. suggestion just try to implement this.
NSMutableSet *mset = [NSMutableSet new];
[mset addObjectsFromArray:currentArray];
[mset addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
NSLog(@"%@",mset);

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSMutableSet instead NSArray. The NSSet class have a methods like *-(void)setSet:(NSSet *)otherSet*. NSSet's (and NSMutableSet's) are testing whether double objects.